Slope and Aspect layers masked when using ee.Terrain
I am trying to create a slope and aspect layer using mosaicked 1m and 2m LiDAR scans. The DEM appears fine but the slope and aspect layer are masked. I've put my code below.
I'm quite new to GEE. The lidar scans were uploaded through Google Cloud and imported as legacy assets.
var aoi = ee.FeatureCollection(boundary)

//vis params
var aoivis = aoi.style({fillColor: '#00000000'})
var lidarvis = {min:0,max:1200};

//mosaic
var lidar = ee.ImageCollection([lidar1m, lidar2m]).mosaic().clip(aoi).select('b1');

//calcs
var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(lidar)
var aspect = ee.Terrain.aspect(lidar)

//add layers
Map.addLayer(aoivis,null,'Border')
Map.addLayer(lidar,lidarvis,'DEM')
Map.addLayer(slope, {min: 0, max: 89.99}, 'Slope');
Map.addLayer(aspect, {min: 0, max: 359.99}, 'Aspect');
Map.centerObject(aoi)


Can you share part of your data as a public asset? It might be easier to help that way

Slope and aspect require the input to have a single, "real" projection.  Mosaics don't have one.
You might be able to set a default projection via setDefaultProjection(), but in some circumstances that isn't sufficient and you'll need to force a reproject on to the data.
